# Monkey Talk in Appcelerator titanium

Tags: monkeytalk

During the development of my mobile application there is a need to test the application using automation tool like Monkey Talk. I'm using Titanium Studio (propraitary of Appcelerator Titanium) to develop the application. How do I integrate the monkey talk with Titanium Studio and test the application using Monkey Talk IDE. Can anyone tell me the detailed procedure of how do I integrate the Titanium Studio with Monkey Talk.

Comment: If the developer of Monkey Talk can't provide any help, perhaps this suite isn't the best to use.  http://www.gorillalogic.com/content/how-do-i-integrate-monkey-talk-appcelerator-titanium-studio

Answer (score 1):

Check this below link. It may help you.
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/148256/monkey-talk-integration-with-titanium